# Migração de Angular 5 para 6 rxjs

Tags: angular, angular-6

Bom estou tentando migrar um projeto novo de Angular 5 para 6, mais estou com certa dificuldade do jeito que mudou as funções do rxjs, estou postando abaixo como eu fazia isso no Angular 5 e funcionava do jeito que eu queria, gostaria de uma ajuda para por exemplo fazer essa mesma função abaixo com Angular 6 eu quero preciso que sempre retorna o status como eu fazia porque dependendo do Status eu faço uma coisa ou outra.

Meu Service:

```
  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res)
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

Minha página:

```
  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario)
      .subscribe (
        data => {
          if (data.status == 200) {
            localStorage.setItem("LOGIN_USUARIO_LOGADO", loginUsuario)
            this.router.navigate(['index']);
          }
        },
        error => {
          if (error.status == 401) {
            this.toastr.error("Login", "Usuário Informado Não Foi Encontrando Em Nossa Base De Dados.");
          } else if (error.status == 404) {
              this.toastr.error("Login", "A Senha Informada Está Incorreta.");
          } else if (error.status == 500) {
            this.error = error.json();
            this.toastr.error("Login", error.message); 
          } else if (error.status == 0) {
            this.toastr.error("Login", "Sem Conexão Com O WebService"); 
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Solução:

usuario.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators/';

import { Usuario } from '../vo/Usuario';
import { GlobalVariableService } from '../../global-variable';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuarioService {

  private apiUrl = this.globalVariableService.apiURL + 'usuario';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private globalVariableService : GlobalVariableService) { 

  }

  saveUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<any> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });    

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, usuario,
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res),
        catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error))
      );
  }

  updateUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Response> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.put(this.apiUrl, usuario,
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res),
        catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error))
      );
  }

  deleteUsuarioById(codigoUsuario: number): Observable<Response> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.delete(this.apiUrl + '/' + codigoUsuario,
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res),
        catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error))
      );
  }

  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'loginUsuario': loginUsuario,
      'senhaUsuario': senhaUsuario
    });

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/',
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res),
        catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error))
      );
  }

  esqueceuSenha(emailUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'emailUsuario': emailUsuario
    });

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/esqueceuSenha/',
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res),
        catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error))
      );
  }
}
```

Minha chamada no Component:

usuario.create.component.ts

```
  callSave () {

    if (this.usuarioForm.valid) {

      let usuario: Usuario = new Usuario
      usuario.nomeUsuario = this.usuarioForm.controls['nomeUsuario'].value;
      usuario.loginUsuario = this.usuarioForm.controls['loginUsuario'].value;
      usuario.senhaUsuario = this.usuarioForm.controls['senhaUsuario'].value;
      usuario.emailUsuario = this.usuarioForm.controls['emailUsuario'].value;

      this.usuarioService.saveUsuario(usuario)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe (
          data => {
            if (data.status == 201) {
              this.toastr.success("Usuário", "Usuário Incluído Com Sucesso.");
              this.usuarioForm.reset();
            }
          },
          error => {
            debugger;
            if (error.status == 0) {
              this.toastr.error("Usuário", "Sem Conexão Com O WebService."); 
            } else if (error.status == 409) {
              this.toastr.info("Usuário", "Já Existe Esse Usuário Cadastrado, Informe Outro."); 
            } else if (error.status == 500) {
              this.toastr.error("Usuário", error.message); 
            }
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ederson, no teu caso **catch** vira **catchError**, ele e o **map** agora devem ser importador de **rxjs/operators**. Segue o exemplo:

```
this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
  .pipe(
    map((res:Response) => res),
    catchError((error:any) => Observable.throw(error))
  );
```

Para melhor entendimento fiz um exemplo de como ficaria os teus métodos no padrão angular/rxjs 6. Clique aqui no [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muh4fg) para visualização.

Dúvidas estou a disposição.

Comment: Muito bom amigo, implementei aqui deu de boa, na verdade ficou mais fácil que eu estava imaginando, eu estava lendo as documentação e não estava entendo as mudanças tinha tentando fazer as chamadas de várias maneiras já e nenhuma estava dando certo, como você fez praticamente é só colocar dentro do pipe, eu queria tirar uma dúvida em relação a duas coisas que eu não sei para que serve por exemplo. no   ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

Comment: e também para o que serve também o takeUntil que você colocou.

Comment: O **takeUntil** foi utilizado justamente para que seja feito o **unsubscribe** do método login ao ser emitido um valor pela variável **ngUnsubscribe**. Quando o componente é destruido (método **ngOnDestroy**), emitimos o **ngUnsubscribe** (**this.ngUnsubscribe.next()**) o que faz com que o **takeUntil** faça o **unsubscribe** do método login.

Comment: Favor me informar se ficou claro a explicação :D

Comment: Eu entendi amigo, mas mais uma coisa é o seguinte quando dá erro no programa está funcionando direitinho, mais agora quando é um retorno OK tipo 200 ou 201 o data vem null, você sabe o que pode ser???

Comment: Bom achei a solução não sei se é a maneira mais correta mas fico desse jeito acima tinha que passar esse observe: 'response' em cada chamada no service para vir o data quando for alguma requisição OK, mas resolveu totalmente o problema.